# Using property vs getter/setter in object's own class

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit, getter-setter

Say I have a class A that has another class B as its property.

When class A needs to do modifications to class B, is it better to use the getter method to do modifications or access the property directly to access?

So as an example.

```
public class Car() {
    private $engine;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->$engine = new Engine();
    }

    public function getEngine() {
        return $this->engine;
    }

    public function replaceEngine() {
        // Should I use
        $this->engine->change();

        // Or should I use
        $this->getEngine()->change();
    }
}
```

I am thinking using the getter method so that if I had to stub Class Engine methods, I can mock what getEngine() returns and remove the dependency.

But I'd like to see more opinions on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opinion based questions don't do well on stack overflow, but you really should use getters and setters.

This method is better programming practice for several reasons.

-You can easily use mock classes

-If you need the class to update in response to have an attribute change (or may in the future). E.g: The setSpouse function can update both the 'spouse' and 'relationshipStatus' attributes

-If you ever want to do refactoring

Comment: Thanks @Angzuril for the tips.

I am not quite understanding your second point. Can you elaborate it a bit more please?

Comment: @DiegoFu The specific case I was thinking of is for when you are setting the attribute of an instance. If you have an instance of Person with attribute 'spouse', when you set 'spouse' to John, the attribute 'relationshipStatus' should change to 'married'. If there are multiple locations in the code that could call setSpouse, it is good if that method would deal with relationshipStatus as well.